# What was Faraday's experiment's of induction?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, magnetic-fields, experimental-physics, electromagnetic-induction

I'm searching about the experiments, which Faraday has done in order to discover the electromagnetic induction phenomenon. I didn't find what I need on google scholar nor google books. Can you recommend me a certain textbook?

Answer (score 1):

> When Michael Faraday made his discovery of electromagnetic induction in 1831, he hypothesized that a changing magnetic field is necessary
>   to induce a current in a nearby circuit. To test his hypothesis he
>   made a coil by wrapping a paper cylinder with wire. He connected the
>   coil to a galvanometer, and then moved a magnet back and forth inside
>   the cylinder.
>
> When you move the magnet back and forth, notice that the galvanometer
>   needle moves, indicating that a current is induced in the coil. Notice
>   also that the needle immediately returns to zero when the magnet is
>   not moving. Faraday confirmed that a moving magnetic field is
>   necessary in order for electromagnetic induction to occur.

This is straight from a Florida State University's webpage https://micro.magnet.fsu.edu/electromag/java/faraday2/